# Wait for MediaScanner to scan file

Tags: java, android

I have a problem with the MediaScanner. I'm taking a picture with the native camera app, and I want to set an ImageView to this image. It works when I chose a picture from the gallery, but I can't get the app to wait for the MediaScanner to complete the scan of my newly taken image. This is my code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE) {
            final boolean isCamera;
            if (data == null) {
                isCamera = true;
            } else {
                final String action = data.getAction();
                if (action == null) {
                    isCamera = false;
                } else {
                    isCamera = action
                            .equals(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
            }

            Uri selectedImageUri;
            if (isCamera) {
                selectedImageUri = outputFileUri;
            } else {
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

                Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(
                        selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                selectedImageUri = Uri.parse(cursor.getString(columnIndex));
                cursor.close();
            }
            // The app is not waiting for these lines, 
            // I have also tried them alone each of them.
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
                    outputFileUri));
            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED,
                    outputFileUri));

            final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImageUri.toString(), options);
            options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options,
                    dpToPx(100), dpToPx(100));

            // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
            options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
            Bitmap bMapRotate = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(
                    selectedImageUri.toString(), options);

            int width = bMapRotate.getWidth();
            int height = bMapRotate.getHeight();
            pic1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPic1);
            int viewHeight = pic1.getLayoutParams().height;
            int viewWidth = pic1.getLayoutParams().width;
            if (width > height)
                viewHeight = height;
            else
                viewWidth = width;
            if (bMapRotate != null) {
                pic1.setImageBitmap(bMapRotate);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried this way:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
    new String[] { outputFileUri.toString() }, null,
    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            setImage(selectedImageUri);
        }
    });
```

Insted of the

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
                    outputFileUri));
sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_FINISHED,
                    outputFileUri));
```

And then having the setImage code in the setImage method, which should be called when the scan is completed, but it still doesn't wait for the scan to be completed? It is just a single file who is scanned, so I don't think it should be that complicated? Should I use AsyncTask or do you have any other suggestions?

**EDIT:**
As it turns out, this was not the problem. The problem was that the Uri had the "file:/" in front of the path, which was not how it should be to be read by the rest of the code.

Comment: `I can't get the app to wait for the MediaScanner to complete the scan of my newly taken image`. Please tell why you want that as I do not understand your problem.

Comment: Because it throws a nullPointerException, since the app can't locate the image from the camera. If i don't have the media scanner, and i go to the gallery, my images are not created there.

Comment: Maybe you should spend a little more time on making the question, because this is not very informative

Answer (score 0):

Based on your onActivityResult block, I see that you are using android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE in the original Intent.

Take a look at this [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intents). It shows how you can include an Uri along with the Intent for the device's camera to save the image file.

As to how to get an Uri, look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media).

In short, if you specify a path for the image file to be saved, you can just refer to that path in your onActivityResult(). The file may not have a corresponding entry in the MediaStore, but it should be readable and available to put in your ImageView.

Comment: I have applied this, and i just results in a blank image when I use the camera.